# responsive email - lotus table width

Tags: css, html-email, responsive

I create a responsive email template at 2 colonne,

```
<style type="text/css">@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { table[class=contenttable] {width:320px !important;}}</style>
<table width="640" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contenttable" border="1" style="margin: auto;">
    <tr><td>
        <table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
          <tr><td>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="mini2/p.jpg">
                </a>
            </td></tr>
        </table><table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="right">
            <tr><td>
                <a href=" ">
                    <img src="mini2/pr.jpg"></a>
            </td></tr>
        </table><table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
          <tr><td>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="mini2/p.jpg">
                </a>
            </td></tr>
        </table><table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="right">
            <tr><td>
                <a href=" ">
                    <img src="mini2/pr.jpg"></a>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

My problem, is Lotus doesn't care about the table width="640" 
So the result is one long line.
Have you any hack?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or codepen so that we can view the page

Comment: https://codepen.io/gotcha5832/pen/wyKqMj

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing tables. One is the conventional way of adding another row in HTML, between your first two tables and second is adding ghost column.

**Adding a row:**

```html
<table width="640" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contenttable" style="margin: auto;">
    <tr>
  <td>
   <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
     <tr>
      <td>
     <a href="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="320" style="width:100%; max-width: 320px; height:auto;">
     </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
    <tr><td>
     <a href=" ">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="320" style="width:100%; max-width: 320px; height:auto;">
     </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table width="50%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
     <tr><td>
     <a href="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="320" style="width:100%; max-width: 320px; height:auto;">
     </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
    <tr><td>
     <a href="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="320" style="width:100%; max-width: 320px; height:auto;">
     </a>
    </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
      </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The changes i have done to your code above are:

- Removed the align rights and added only align left
- Changed your table widths to 50%
- Added a row between

Although this method works, I have another method below, ghost columns which allows us to add columns (or even rows) which is read by email clients that use Outlook and IE to render emails.

**Ghost Columns:**

```html
<table width="640" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contenttable" style="margin: auto;">
    <tr>
  <td>
   <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
     <tr>
      <td>
     <a href="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="320" style="width:100%; max-width: 320px; height:auto;">
     </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
   </td><td>
   <![endif]-->
   <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
    <tr><td>
     <a href=" ">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="320" style="width:100%; max-width: 320px; height:auto;">
     </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  
   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
   </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
   <![endif]-->
   <table width="50%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
     <tr><td>
     <a href="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="320" style="width:100%; max-width: 320px; height:auto;">
     </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
   </td><td>
   <![endif]-->
   <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
    <tr><td>
     <a href="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="320" style="width:100%; max-width: 320px; height:auto;">
     </a>
    </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
      </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I have done the same changes as above. Let me know if any of these work for you. You can simply copy paste the codes to your email and test it.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @syfer.
Unfortunately, I couldn't try it, as I just get temporary access to emailacid. I can only tell you my last version was ok.